# calculating days

Tags: php

I want to calculate the no of days from a field where I enter the dates from calendar like `21 jan 2011`, but when  I use `count()` it will only count the whole string, how can I count the days?

Comment: do you mean get the day in php or difference between two days?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you have a look at the [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method.

For example

```
$date1 = new \DateTime('21 Jan 2011');
$date2 = new \DateTime('28 Feb 2011');

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

$days = $diff->d;
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume your date is using the date object [ http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php ]. If so, you could use something like this [ http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/calculating-difference-between-dates-php-051018-1024/ ] to calculate the difference between two dates. I presume that's what you're intending to do.

If you're not already using the date object, you can convert to the date object fairly easily. The tutorial linked to above demonstrates converting a string to a date using the explode function.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo date('d',strtotime('21 jan 2011'));
```

see this function for more [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = "21 jan 2011";
$days = explode(" ", $date);
$days = $days[0];
```